# Understanding the unitary equivalence between normal operator and multiplication operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of the theorem IX.4.6 from Conway's A course in functional analysis. I trying to understand the proof of unitary equivalence of normal operator and multiplication operator. [image: page No 272 of Conway]

Here I am not understanding how $X$ is taking as "disjoint" sum, I mean $X_1$ and $X_2$ can be non-disjoint. so how this disjoint union is taking!

secondly, The map $U$ defined here how this map is surjective ! what will be inverse image of arbitrary element!

Please Help me. This is very needful for me now. Thanks.